# How do I disable RDS performance insights for a t4g MySQL instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm trying to temporarily *dis*able performance insights for an RDS MySQL t4g instance (which is using the latest MySQL version and has performance insights already enabled and in effect). The RDS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PerfInsights.Enabling.html) describes a "Performance Insights" section where this can be toggled, which I remember using when setting up the instance:[image: Screenshot of the RDS documentation describing how to enable/disable performance insights]

**But this section is entirely missing when I go to the "Modify" view from the instance page.** This is true even when I click on the option to "Modify retention tier" from the performance insights page directly:[image: Prompt on the performance insights page to change from the default retention tier]

Also (and I'm only mentioning this as possibly another effect of the same underlying issue), when I've visited the insights page for this instance in the past couple days, about 2 out of 3 times all the performance insight data over any timespan just appears as `NaN`, even after a system update and multiple reboots.

[image: Empty performance insights metrics]

I do get these metrics to appear if I hard refresh enough times, but for another instance it always shows up right away.

I have combed over the [entire](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_PerfInsights.html) performance insights documentation and have not found any reason why this section wouldn't appear, but I feel like I'm missing something that would be causing this to happen. Is there anywhere else I should be looking?

**EDIT: I just tried to change a different (unrelated) setting on the same instance and got this message that my instance with already-enabled performance insights doesn't support performance insights, so I have to disable it...when I don't even have the option!
[image: Yeah, I'm trying to disable it...]**

Comment: We went through something similar, had a couple of db.t4g.small instances with PI enabled, now we want to create a new t4g.small with PI enabled but cannot do it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this very annoying problem as well, to get around this I used AWS CloudShell and gave the CLI command to disable performance insights.

```
aws rds modify-db-instance
--db-instance-identifier sample-db-instance
--no-enable-performance-insights
```